# How to properly refactor some copy/pasted code

Tags: c#, refactoring

I am building a command-line exe that can apply several operations on a PDF file (add text, images, resize, crop, etc).

Currently, my Program.cs looks a bit like this (it uses [CommandLineParser](https://github.com/gsscoder/commandline/)):

```
switch (invokedVerb)
{
    case "barcode":
        Operations.BarcodeOperations.AddBarCode(options.AddBarcodeVerb);
        break;

    case "addblankpage":
        Operations.PageOperations.AddBlankPage(options.AddBlankPageVerb);
        break;
}
```

As you can see, I have split the operations into several XXXOperations classes, each of them having very similar instructions:

```
public static void AddStuff(StuffOptions options)
{
    Logging.Log("here is a bunch of logging");

    // here sometimes there is some action-specific code but not often

    using (DocWrapper doc = new DocWrapper(options.File)) // this is in all actions
    {
        foreach (int page in doc.GetPagesToModify(options.Pages)) // this is in most actions
        {
            // call some stuff on the doc instance
        }

        doc.Save(options.OutputFile); // this is in all actions
    }
}
```

So, all actions create a new instance of DocWrapper, most of them loop on its pages (but I could modify the actions so that all of them do), and all of them save, but each of them do a different set of actions inside it.

How could I refactor this code so that the DocWrapper instantiation, the pages loop and the save are in a single place, but I can specify custom code inside the loop ?

I'm thinking of using delegates or Actions to define my actions, but I have no idea where to start, since I'm not very familiar with them.

Thanks!

Comment: your question is off topic on SO, try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution and posted it [at CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/61942/how-to-refactor-to-externalize-some-work-inside-a-loop/61949)

> Here is what I have done so far:
>
> I have created a Worker class with my redundant code:
>
> ```
> public static void DoWorkOnPages(IProgramOptions options, Action<DocWrapper, int> actions)
> {
>     using (DocWrapper doc = new DocWrapper(options.File))
>     {
>         foreach (int page in doc.GetPagesToModify(options.Pages).OrderBy(p => p))
>         {
>             actions(doc, page);
>         }
>
>         doc.Save(options.OutputFile);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> And in each XXXOperations class my methods calls it like this:
>
> ```
> public static void AddBarStuff(StuffOptions options)
> {
>     Logging.Log("Here is a magnificient function");
>
>     using (Image barcode = CreateStuffImage(someParameters))
>     {
>         Worker.DoWorkOnPages(options, (doc, page) =>
>             {
>                 // do something with options, doc, page and barcode
>             });
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Obviously, for in the operations that do not quite exactly work like
>   this, I had to duplicate some code, but I guess it can't be helped.
>
> If you come up with a more elegant, more simple, more powerful
>   solution or just a different one, I'll gladly upvote it.